# Gluon Mobile and background services

Tags: android, windows, gluon-mobile

I have a prototype application that uses Gluon Mobile. It's nominally targeted at Android, but it's really nice to be able to develop and debug most things on Windows.

One of the things the app does is receive remote data (e.g., over BLE, sockets, etc.). When running on Android this works fine so long as the application is in the foreground and running, but if it goes into the background then it stops receiving data. Turning off battery optimization allows it to continue working even when the screen is off, but it still doesn't work if it ends up in the background (e.g., I start using another app) or if the app is closed.

What I'd like is to be able to always collect data in the background, so when the app is brought to the foreground it can display everything and not be missing a bunch of data.

What is the Gluon Mobile way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Is the app running a Foreground Service?

Comment: No, although I'd be fine with that. I just don't know how to do that with Gluon Mobile.